# use npm package to validate a package name

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a way to use the npm package to validate a package name?

```
const npm = require('npm');

const isValid = npm.validatePackageName('foobar'); // true
const isValid = npm.validatePackageName('-4! *'); // false
```

I see a userland package that does this, but surely the npm package itself can do this? Is there a public utility exported from that package?

Comment: the package in the answer is the official package by npm itself so they might not have included this inside their npm package. In future they might but not right now. Currently, they only support the commands via code like npm.commands.install([<package_list_array>, cb]);

Answer (score 19):

**Valid Names**

```
var validate = require("validate-npm-package-name")

validate("some-package")
validate("example.com")
validate("under_score")
validate("123numeric")
validate("excited!")
validate("@npm/thingy")
validate("@jane/foo.js")
```

**All of the above names are valid, so you'll get this object back:**

```
{
  validForNewPackages: true,
  validForOldPackages: true
}
```

**Invalid Names**

```
validate(" leading-space:and:weirdchars")
```

**That was never a valid package name, so you get this:**

```
{
  validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [
    'name cannot contain leading or trailing spaces',
    'name can only contain URL-friendly characters'
  ]
}
```

source : https://github.com/npm/validate-npm-package-name

Comment: You said "excited!" is a valid name. But @nikhil sugandh said "Package name should not contain any of the following characters: ~)('!*". Which one is correct? Can a valid name contains "!" or not?

Comment: According to the `package-json` doc (10.4.0), it states: "The names of scoped packages can begin with a dot or an underscore. This is not permitted without a scope." Does anyone know if this implies; (a) @_scope/foobar, or (b) @scope/_foobar ... it's a bit confusing. Also I don't believe anyone ever tests for this condition!

Answer (score 3):

Naming Rules:

Below is a list of rules that valid npm package name should conform to:

> - Package name length should be greater than zero.
> - All the characters in the package name must be lowercase i.e., no uppercase 
>     or mixed case names are allowed.
> - Package name can consist of hyphens.
> - Package name must not contain any non-url-safe characters (since name ends 
>     up being part of a URL).
> - Package name should not start with `.` or `_`.
> - Package name should not contain any leading or trailing spaces.
> - Package name should not contain any of the following characters: `~)('!*`
> - Package name cannot be the same as a node.js/io.js core module nor a 
>     reserved/blacklisted name. For example, the following names are invalid:
>
>   - `http`
>   - `stream`
>   - `node_modules`
>   - `favicon.ico`
> - Package name length cannot exceed 214.

Your package name consist of `*`; that is where the problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Nikita Ivanov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270070/1724702), covering more invalid cases. Code:

```js
var validate = require("validate-npm-package-name");

function printPackageNameValidationFor(packageName) {
  console.log(packageName);
  console.log(validate(packageName));
  console.log();
}

// valid
printPackageNameValidationFor("dashes-hyphens-minus-sign-valid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("example.com-periods-valid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("under_scores-valid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("example-123-numbers-valid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("123-starting-with-numbers-valid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("@scope/at-sign-for-scope-names-valid");

// invalid
printPackageNameValidationFor("slashes@using-at-sign-for-non-scopename-uses-invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("slashes/on-nonscoped-names-invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("pipes|invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("exclamations!for!new!packages!invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("space invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("html%20entities-invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("square[brackets]-invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("commas,invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("colon:invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("semicolon;invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("single-quote\'invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("double-quote\"invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("tilde~invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("simple-(brackets)-invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("curly-{braces}-invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("asterisks*-invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("carets^-invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("pound-sign#-invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("plus-sign+-invalid");
printPackageNameValidationFor("question-mark?-invalid");
```

Output, valid names:

```
dashes-hyphens-minus-sign-valid
{ validForNewPackages: true, validForOldPackages: true }

example.com-periods-valid
{ validForNewPackages: true, validForOldPackages: true }

under_scores-valid
{ validForNewPackages: true, validForOldPackages: true }

example-123-numbers-valid
{ validForNewPackages: true, validForOldPackages: true }

123-starting-with-numbers-valid
{ validForNewPackages: true, validForOldPackages: true }

@scope/at-sign-for-scope-names-valid
{ validForNewPackages: true, validForOldPackages: true }
```

Output, invalid names:

```
slashes@using-at-sign-for-non-scopename-uses-invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

slashes/on-nonscoped-names-invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

pipes|invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

exclamations!for!new!packages!invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: true,
  warnings:
   [ 'name can no longer contain special characters ("~\'!()*")' ] }

space invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

html%20entities-invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

square[brackets]-invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

commas,invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

colon:invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

semicolon;invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

single-quote'invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: true,
  warnings:
   [ 'name can no longer contain special characters ("~\'!()*")' ] }

double-quote"invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

tilde~invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: true,
  warnings:
   [ 'name can no longer contain special characters ("~\'!()*")' ] }

simple-(brackets)-invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: true,
  warnings:
   [ 'name can no longer contain special characters ("~\'!()*")' ] }

curly-{braces}-invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

asterisks*-invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: true,
  warnings:
   [ 'name can no longer contain special characters ("~\'!()*")' ] }

carets^-invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

pound-sign#-invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

plus-sign+-invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }

question-mark?-invalid
{ validForNewPackages: false,
  validForOldPackages: false,
  errors: [ 'name can only contain URL-friendly characters' ] }
```